# How to make a decision based on the variable type?

Tags: angular, typescript, variables

I have a basic variable which is in string format. I want to make a decision in the code based on the type of the variable. I have the below code.

```
var typeOfVariable = typeof(chai);
console.log(typeOfVariable); //getting output as number

if (typeOfVariable = 'string'){
    chai = parseFloat(chai); // throwing error here
}
```

I have logged 'typeOfVariable' and getting as number. However, the code is also entering the if condition. Any ideas on why this is happening.

Comment: What you are doing (single `=`) is an assignment. You want to do a comparison: `if (typeOfVariable === 'string')`

Comment: If you don't know the basics of Javascript, maybe you should learn Javascript **before** learning Angular and Typescript ... The comparison is `==` or `===`, `===` being prefered.

Comment: `typeOfVariable = 'string'` should be `typeOfVariable === 'string'`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make a decision on the type in typescript, you could use a [type guard](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html):

```
function padLeft(value: string, padding: string | number) {
    if (typeof padding === "number") {
        return Array(padding + 1).join(" ") + value;
    }
    if (typeof padding === "string") {
        return padding + value;
    }
    throw new Error(`Expected string or number, got '${padding}'.`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In if condition you have assigned 'string' to typeofVariable instead of comparing it. It should be

```
if(typeOfVariable === 'string')
```